# input type="password" shows text using HTML 5 on IE 11

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

Here is the basic format of html input

```
   <input id="Password1" type="password" />
```

It displays text instead of password type.

Comment: Not for me, it doesn't.  There must be something else at play here.  Are you sure there are no typing mistakes in your html?

Comment: It works for me - http://plnkr.co/edit/HRrUFMwNEqZ5b5ILXsnT?p=preview

Comment: It shows if the 'Eye' is selected. It is a feature - http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/wiki/ie11-iewindows8_1/the-use-of-the-password-reveal-eye-button-in-ie10/19a9dee2-fb0c-4c26-a6bc-ac02cf98d80e

Comment: I checked my HTML code but didn;'t find any mistake.

Comment: Create a simple html file that has nothing in it but the code in your question.  Let us know if that does the same thing.

Comment: I created simple aspx page and include my master page , it shows same problem but later , i created different apx page again and didn't iclude my master page and it worked fine

Comment: So something in your master page is breaking it.  Also, I suggested a html file, not an aspx page.  You completely missed the point, but at least you're getting somewhere now and you know where to look.

Comment: I m sorry for missing completely your point anyway.. It is in master page . i  located the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That looks right.  Do you have a link to an example?  Maybe it's other html that isn't closed properly.  I'd switch type and id just to see if it makes any difference.

Comment: Normally i musing different  id for my input , i thought this is the reason of the problem , but i used this raw , basic format of html input type =password , even that one types as text

Comment: Try it here:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type

It's definitely working there as you've typed it.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue

If you add placeholder  in `<input id="Password1" type="password" placeholder="type your password" />` it will work in any condition .